# Change filename in the patch OR Editing patch such a way that patch remains valid

Tags: linux, git, patch

can we edit the patch in a such a way that it remains valid even after edit?

We have a patch which applies to one source tree, now to support other platform we copied the configuration files and renamed, some of the patches would remain the same but it should contain the new file-name.
Is there a way to edit patch and keeping patch valid in this situation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, patch files are text files and can be edited manually if done with care.

The file names are in the hunk headers:

```
--- a/filename  details
+++ b/filename  details
@@ -X1,L1 +X2,L2 @@
```

The `details` (modified date, usually) are ignored, and the `a`/`b` are dummy directories to make `patch` happy thinking that the original file is different from the modified one (that's the 1 in `patch -p1`).

The numbers `X1`,`X2` are the original and modified line numbers where the hunk begins. The `L1` and `L2` numbers are the original and modified lenghts of the chunk.

And that's all! Just change `filename` on both `+++` and `---` lines and everything just works.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I modified the patch and it still applies well :)